# JavaScript file not reloading in browser when modified on server

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-2.0

So I have this ASP.Net 2.0 website that uses functions contained within a JS file. When a webpage loads the js file loads fine. But when I change something in that file on the server the changes are not propagated to user's browser. It keeps working according to the out dated file. How can I force the browser to reload the modified file from the server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One rather common solution (that is also used here at SO I think) is to add a query string to the url of the javascript file, containing a version number. When you change the query string, the browser will treat it as a new file and download it rather than picking it from the cache.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/file.js?v=2"></script>
```

In the above example, changing `file.js?v=2` to `file.js?v=3` would force the browser to download the file, instead of loading the cached `file.js?v=2`.

Comment: Note: if you open the chrome Inspector, it may cause to use cached js files even by Ctrl+F5. you can use `Disable cache` from `Network tab` of inspector to force load fresh copies while DevTools/Inspector is open

Answer (score 10):

In general, the quickest way to force update is to press **CTRL+F5** in the browser.

Otherwise you need to empty the browser's cache.

If you are using Firefox I'd recommend the plugin [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60), where you easily can just click "Misc -> Clear Private Data -> Cache".