# Not Updating javascript file

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on ASP.NET MVC4 Project. When i am updating  JavaScript file and run my project in browsers. New changes do not reflected on page  Same thing happen when I am trying on IIS Server. For that every time I have to remove browser history then it reflects but this is not correct way after deployment

Is there any other way for that?

Please guide me Thanks in advance

Comment: Hit CTRL + F5 when the browser loads your site.

Comment: Thanks for reply but when if project already deployed  and i change in JavaScript file and deploy file then how could it possible to notify every client for  use CTRL + F5 for new change

Comment: What you can do is ask the client themselves. It is not always the case, I mean many a times it just works. But it is still a good thing to let people know.

Comment: @progrAmmar THANK YOU!!

Comment: Press `Ctrl+Shift+R ` to clean cache.

Comment: @progrAmmar I forget about Ctrl+F5 a lot.  Thanks, that worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### Your problem would be:

1. **Browser Caching JavaScript**

Check whether the browser is caching the javascript. To do it, check the header of the javascript on the browser for the attribute **Cache-Control** in the browser. Case yes, configure **Cache-Control** to **no-cache** on the project. Disable cache only in your development environment.

2. **Visual Studio or IIS not reloading the javascripts**

Check whether the **Visual Studio** or **IIS** are reloading your entire project after the deploy.

#### Suggestions to solve your problem:

Solutions to solve this problem is version the javascript.

1. **Using different names**

One way to ensure that the user will receive a fresh version of javascript is versioning the filename.
Instead of use only the name, you can concatenate a `version` number to the javascript.

Example:

```
www.example.com/script.8238823.js
www.example.com/script.3434342.js
```

This urls represent different paths and the browser will update.

2. **Using query string**

Another way is use a query string such `v=` + `version`.
The `version` can be a MD5 hash, or the timestamps or the size in bytes of the file.

Example:

```
www.example.com/script.js?v=999990
www.example.com/script.js?v=129
```

This force the browser to cache the file, and reload when the version of `v`, change.

I don't use ASP.NET, but I think that exists solutions for this.

Comment: Using query string is more easy to implement. But, the best options is with different names. Some ISPs and CDN ignore the query string, treat as the same file .

Answer (score 0):

I saw similar answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339887/javascript-file-not-reloading-in-browser-when-modified-on-server) which I think would help you. Specifically, the suggestion of adding a query parameter to the end of the URL which references your JavaScript file, so you can "version" them.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same problem. For my ASP.NET MVC4 project I had an Azure database and web app. The reason the javascript file was not updating was because the connection to the database had lapsed. Refreshing in Server Explorer solved the issue / reestablishing the connection with a new login fixed the issue.

Also make sure the way you are publishing has the correct database admin login and connection.

Answer (score -1):

Are you using the [MVC Bundle](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)? By using bundle and js inclusion as  @Scripts.Render("file name used in the bundle config file") should not sustain cache.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the BundleConfig.cs. Actually during run-time such inclusion of resources like js, css has a variable hash attached to end of the file e.g. `somefile.js?v=#hash#`, where the hash is evaluated based on contents of such resources, thus any change would change the hash too.